# behavior of text area placed into a div with css columns

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, multiple-columns

I was wondering if there is any way to style textArea, placed into a div with css columns properties.

My textArea styled with a border and has resizable height property. So I want users to type into text area and when its divided into two columns, first column doesn't lose its bottom border and second doesn't lose its top border.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-columns: 2 200px;
  -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
}

textarea {
  height: 700px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  outline:none;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

For some reasons I try to avoid solutions based on the 'contenteditable' parameter.

At the same time it seems that css-columns doesn't affect the textArea in Firefox.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0xgXAqa2h2EKEl8BxyaQ?p=preview) is my plunker, so u can run it both in Firefox and Chrome to compare.

Comment: can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: Hi! I've updated my post with a plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `textarea` is a single element, I don't think you're going to be able to place arbitrary borders where it splits between the columns. You could consider a pair of floating `div` elements that each contain a narrow green rule to fake the top and bottom borders, but that would be defeated if you continue to allow your users to resize the `textarea` element.

Also, based on what I can see, while Chrome happily splits your `textarea` between the columns, Firefox is not so generous. Both, however, split a regular paragraph of text with no issues: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/r2hFj/.

May I ask why you want to split a `textarea` this way?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mike! As a result I want to refuse from scroll, so I need an alternative way to navigate through the textArea, cause its wrapper is limited in height.

Comment: You still have my curiosity, @breath ... what are you doing that requires the user to type into a textarea that spans two columns? If you're able to tell me a bit more about your use case, perhaps I could offer a different solution that will work for your project.

Comment: Mike, thank you for willing to help me! This mostly design issue. Regular text is displayed in columns and as seen from your fiddle both browsers doing it well. I want to have a minimum of changes in page style when switching to edit mode (its only border appears around the text). This need to be done cross-browser and as simple as possible. Now I'm writing a script by which I want to combine two textAreas, but it seems too big and too slow for this task.

Comment: Are you looking at any jQuery text editor plug-ins for this kind of task? I was looking at an unanswered question this morning and see there's quite a few to choose from. Perhaps one of them could work with your design requirements. Here's a list from January that compiles a few: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2014/01/latest-jquery-rich-text-editor-plugins.html. I also found this tutorial on inline page editing using a library called popline: http://spyrestudios.com/html5-inline-text-editing-popline/. I hope these help!

Comment: This is the best solution for such case, indeed, so I mark your answer as correct. But I will continue with my script, because "contenteditable"-solutions not suitable for my task.

Comment: Much obliged and very best of luck with your project.